# How to remap Caps Lock key to a command (not ctrl or escape, but a command like xfce4-terminal)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, wayland

I am using GNOME on Wayland on Arch Linux.
Currently my CapsLock key does nothing and "Both shift keys" act as CapsLock (set from gnome-tweaks).
I want to remap CapsLock to a command like `gnome-terminal` / `xfce4-terminal` / `anything else` so that when I press CapsLock that command is executed (and so the terminal is opened in this case)
How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), it has a graphical interface that allows you to set up both the shortcut and the command to execute (python).

- [Wiki/scripting](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Scripting)